# Bounded self-adjoint linear operator is injective...

Tags: functional-analysis, self-adjoint-operators

Let $T : H → H$ be a bounded self–adjoint linear operator on a Hilbert space $H$. Suppose
the range $R(T)$ is dense in $H$. Prove that $T$ is injective.

Comment: I want to show that the null space only contains zero, but I am confused in where to go.

Answer (score 0):

We have $R(T)^{\perp}=\overline{R(H)}^{\perp}=H^{\perp}=\{0\}$, but $\ker T^{\ast}=(R(T))^{\perp}$.

Comment: So how do we know that the range is closed? We only know that the range of T is dense.

Comment: Okay, just made a mistake, we don't need that. Just keep in mind that $A^{\perp}=\overline{A}^{\perp}$.

Comment: Isn't $R(T)$ _always_ dense for all bounded self-adjoint operators on $H$?